# Lemoine Point triangle

Tags: triangles

from Wolfram MathWorld, I know there is a Lemoine point of triangle, also called symmedian point, the sum of squared distances of this point to all the three sides is algebraically **minimum**.
How can I get the point **(X,Y)** of the lemoine point when I have **only** the **vertexes** of the triangle ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Barycentric coordinates of the Symmedian point 
($a^2:b^2:c^2$) together with 
[conversion between barycentric and Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system)
provide a nice and simple solution
for the Cartesian coordinates of 
the Symmedian point $K=(K_x,K_y)$
as a weighted average of the coordinates of vertices of $\triangle ABC,$
$A=(A_x,A_y),$ 
$B=(B_x,B_y)$ and $C=(C_x,C_y)$:

\begin{align}
K=\frac{a^2\,A+b^2\,B+c^2\,C}{a^2+b^2+c^2},
\end{align}

where $a,b,c$ are lengths of corresponding sides of $\triangle ABC$,
which can be easily obtained from known coordinates of the vertices.